# An error occurred during local report processing when bind the report second time

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, reporting-services

I am using `reportviewer` for reporting the problem is that when i bind report first time means when user select report type from the combobox it display perfectly but when user select second option from the combobox it give me error `An error occurred during local report processing`. For your review i am giving the code

```
switch (cmbReports.SelectedValue.ToString())
                {
     case "01":
     #region Salaries and Wages Ytd
     ReportParameter pCase1 = new ReportParameter("reportHeading", "SALARIES AND WAGES TRENDS (US$) FOR THE YEAR AS AT :" + taxmnth);
     _parmList.Add(pCase1);
     List<FiscalPeriod> _FisclList = new List<FiscalPeriod>();
       if (AcctPrd == crntActPrd)
         _FisclList = _reportComp.getGraphRpt_salWageY2d(crntActPrd);
       else
          _FisclList = _reportComp.getGraphRpt_salWageY2d_hist(AcctPrd);
          ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource("dsFiscalPrd", _FisclList);

           this.reportViewerGraph.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
           LocalReport repCase1 = reportViewerGraph.LocalReport;
           repCase1.DataSources.Clear();
           repCase1.ReportPath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GraphicalReportPath"].ToString() + @"Sal_WagesY2dReport.rdlc";
           repCase1.SetParameters(_parmList);
           repCase1.DataSources.Add(rds1);
           repCase1.Refresh();
           this.reportViewerGraph.RefreshReport();
         #endregion
            break;
       case "02":
             printType();
           #region Incomes Ytd
            ReportParameter pCase2 = new ReportParameter("reportHeading", " INCOMES (US$) FOR THE YEAR AS AT: " + taxmnth);
             _parmList.Add(pCase2);
             List<FiscalPeriod> _FisclList1 = new List<FiscalPeriod>();
             if (AcctPrd == crntActPrd)
                  _FisclList1 = _reportComp.getGraphRpt_WFAnalysisY2d(crntActPrd);
             else
                 _FisclList1 = _reportComp.getGraphRpt_WFAnalysisY2d_hist(AcctPrd);
                 ReportDataSource rds2 = new ReportDataSource("dsfiscalperiod", _FisclList1);

                  this.reportViewerGraph.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                  LocalReport repCase2 = reportViewerGraph.LocalReport;
                  repCase2.DataSources.Clear();
                  repCase2.ReportPath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["GraphicalReportPath"].ToString() + @"IncomesY2dReport.rdlc";
                  repCase2.SetParameters(_parmList);
                  repCase2.DataSources.Add(rds2);
                  repCase2.Refresh();
                  this.reportViewerGraph.RefreshReport();
                #endregion
                  break;
}
```

Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @david99world    i can accept answer but problem is that most of the answer is not woking so how can i do that .

Comment: @david99world only i have upgrade the answer not accept may be you are  saying this really i sorry for that :( i was thinking only upvote is good

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?